Solana Token Metadata Not Updating On Phantom Wallet
My spl-token metadata has been updated on solscan but still shows as "Unknown Token" on my phantom wallet.https://solscan.io/token/9FHWDAhbiAyARChp1CMZEVVX1V9QuxazsQkKG3kzVnAw

Phantom is probably still indexing your transaction and it will show up after some time.
